# GeoJSON filtering based on properties not working

Tags: geoserver, javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am getting the GeoJSON URL from GeoServer and the data is getting displayed on the map using Leaflet. Now I need to display a few of the features based on the property "status" whether it is pass or rescan.

But I'm getting the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

Below is my code:

```
var Dupont = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ABHI/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ABHI:Dupont_new&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson",{dataType:"json"});       
Dupont.addTo(map);


var stataupass=L.geoJson(Dupont, {
 filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return (feature.properties.status)=="rescan";
  }

}).addTo(map);
```

link to [Geojson data](https://jsfiddle.net/mcsp440b/) (fiddle)

Comment: Your sample data works for me so I suspect that you are not getting anything returned in your Ajax call.  So, I don't think it is your filter function that is at fault.  +1 for alerting me to the L.GeoJSON.AJAX plugin though - I've always done old school Ajax calls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[leaflet-ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) plugin gives you directly an `L.GeoJSON` Layer Group (what you record in your `Dupont` variable).

Therefore you cannot feed `Dupont` into another `L.geoJson()` factory: it is not a plain GeoJSON data, but a Leaflet Layer Group. Hence the error message.

If you want to set some options (`filter` in your case) on that Layer Group, you can directly pass `options` as 2nd argument of `L.geoJson.ajax()` factory, even though it is not clearly advertised, exactly like for a regular [`L.GeoJSON`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-options) group (besides the plugin special options):

```js
L.geoJson.ajax(url, {
  dataType: "json",
  filter: fn
});
```